# How can I change the prev / next buttons text to Dutch?

Tags: themes, translation, previous, next

If you look to [this page](http://test.tamarawobben.nl/?p=108) everything is alright except the previous and next buttons text are in English. Does anyone know how I can make them display in Dutch? I already tried to change them but no luck.

**NB:** I'm using Contango theme.

The function looks like this :

```
/** Contango Link Pages */
function contango_link_pages() {

$contango_options = contango_get_settings();    
if( $contango_options['contango_post_style'] != 'excerpt' ) {

        return wp_link_pages( array( 

            'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span class="assistive-text">'. __( 'Pages:', 'contango' ) .'</span>',
            'after' => '</div>',
            'link_before' => '<span>',
            'link_after' => '</span>',
                        'echo' => 0

            )
        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply using one language on your site:

1. Find the utility.php file in your themes folder with location **lib/functions/utility.php**
2. Next find the lines 227 and 231 and
3. change the `__( 'Previous Post', 'contango' )` and `__( 'Next Post', 'contango' )` to your desired values.

For example: `previous_post_link( '%link', __( 'vorige post', 'contango' ) . ' <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>' );`
Make sure you save and overwrite the utilty.php file. Location: **wp-content/themes/contango/lib/functions/utility.php**

If that didn't work try copying the utilty.php file from the server to a new folder on your computer, and check the code to make sure it's correct. If it's wrong, you might need to change your permission rights on the folder your in.

Not the most cleanest of ways but if you're just using one language for your site it won't really matter. Let me know if that changed anything for you?